# Best Practice for repetitive computations

Tags: python, pandas, loops

Cog in the Machine:

Data contains Current 12 months of data and is stacked Horizontally. With each month having updates revised and new month appended to.

```
  ID  |Date        |Month1_a |Month1_b |Month1_c |Month2_a |Month2_b |Month2_c |Month3_a |Month3_b |Month3_c
  ##  |MM/DD/YYYY  |abc      |zxy      |123      |NULL     |zxy      |122      |abc      |zxy      |123
```

Actual data file has no headers and is ingested downstream as distinct File per Month
File Month 1, etc.

```
ID  | Date       |Month1_a |Month1_b |Month1_c |New Column
##  |MM/DD/YYYY  |abc      |zxy      |123      | #

ID  | Date       |Month2_a  |Month2_b |Month2_c |New Column
##  |MM/DD/YYYY  |NULL      |zxy      |122      | #
```

Other than copying the file 12 times. Is there any suggestion for reading once and looping through to create my outputs. I've worked out the logic for Month 1, I'm stuck as to how to move to month 2+.

Was originally thinking Read File > Drop Month 3+ > Drop Month 1 > Run Logic, but I'm not sure if there is a better/best practice.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you use a MultiIndex for the columns?  This would look like [(Month 1, a), (Month 1, b), (Month 1, c), (Month 2, a), ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output n number of csv files where n is the number of months in your input data.  Hopefully this is what you are after.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv', sep='|')

# Strip whitespace from column names
df.columns = [x.strip() for x in df.columns]

# Get a set of months in the data by splitting on _ and removing 'Month' from
# the first part
months = set([x.split('_')[0].replace('Month','') for x in df.columns if 'Month' in x])

# For each numeric month in months, add those columns with that number in it to
# the ID and Date columns and write to a csv with that month number in the csv title
for month in months:
    base_columns = ['ID','Date']
    base_columns.extend([x for x in df.columns if 'Month'+month in x])
    df[base_columns].to_csv(f'Month_{month}.csv', index=False)
```